# C - pointer is not null after freeing it

Tags: c, pointers, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

Does the value of pointer become NULL after freeing it?

```
int* p = malloc(sizeof(*p));

free(p);

if(p==NULL)
    printf("Null\n");
else
    printf("Not null\n");
```

Output:

```
 Not null
```

Well, I assume not;

Anyway, I have asked a question earlier today :

Check it out here: 
[C - How can I free dynamically allocated memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900527/c-how-can-i-free-dynamically-allocated-memory)

```
List* head1 = NULL;

insertFront(&head1, 1);
insertFront(&head1, 2);

print(head1);

while (head1)
{

    List *temp = head1;
    head1 = head1->next;
    free(temp);
}

if(head1 == NULL)
    printf("Null\n");
else
    printf("Not null\n");
```

Output in this case:

```
Null
```

In this case after freeing head1 (nodes also) the head1 becomes null, does'nt it?

And finally, am I missing some concepts?

head1 is null, however p isn't.

My Question is:

**Why values differs between head1 and p?**

Comment: The free function  doesn't and can't null the pointer variable. In order for it to be able to do that, you'd need to pass a pointer to the pointer variable.

Comment: @PSkocik thanks but what about value of head1?

Comment: generally, make it a good habit, after `free`ing up a pointer, **always** set it to `NULL` afterwards, as if you ever de-reference a `NULL` pointer it will crash hinting what happened.

Comment: Of course you print "Null" after the loop `while (head1) {...}`. The variable `head1` is the terminating linked list pointer, not a freed memory pointer supposedly reset.

Comment: You ask why a pointer you don't change differs from a pointer you explicitly change to `NULL`? It is not clear what your problem is: Why is a pig not an eagle?

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah thanks, I have got it now, head1 is nulled for traversing it .

Comment: The value of a pointer becomes *indeterminate* when the object it points to reaches the end of its lifetime. Using the value of such a pointer (even by comparing it to `NULL`) is undefined behavior.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1879550/694576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition of the loop

```
while (head1)
       ^^^^^^
{

    List *temp = head1;
    head1 = head1->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

becomes equal to `false`  when the data member `next` of the next node is equal to NULL

```
head1 = head1->next;
^^^^^         ^^^^^
```

This has nothing common with the function `free`. The function accepts the argument by value. That is it deals with a copy of the original [pointer. So the original pointer itself will not be changed.

Comment: That's perfect! Now I got this! Actually this head is nulled by traversing the linked list, not by freeing it.

Answer (score 5):

Freeing a pointer doesn't change its value.

You need to manually set it to `NULL` after freeing it if that's the behaviour you want.

Comment: Even attempting to read/copy the pointer after freeing it is UB.

Comment: Please see my specific question, that I have included after editing.

Answer (score 4):

When you `free` a pointer, you're not changing its value.  You're just returning whatever memory it points to back to the pool.

In fact, given that `free` takes the *value* of a pointer instead of its *address*, that alone is enough to tell you that the value isn't changed, since there's no way to change it.

The reason `head1` is `NULL` at the end of the loop is because you are modifying the value of `head1` inside the loop to go down the list until it reaches the end.  We know we're at the end of the list when we find a `NULL` value in the `next` pointer.  So at the end of the loop, `head1` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

When you allocate memory, the pointer naturally points to the beginning of the allocated block for you to reference. However, when you free a pointer, only the memory itself is freed.

The catch is that the pointer is still pointing to that location in memory that it was previously set to, even though the value of that block of memory is no longer useful.

Setting to `NULL` is not an automatic operation after freeing.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above freeing a pointer has nothing to do with changing its value. It just tells the memory management that the related block (on the heap) can be reused.

This SO question provides further information: [What is the difference between freeing the pointer and assigning it to NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430819/what-is-the-difference-between-freeing-the-pointer-and-assigning-it-to-null)

Answer (score 0):

free() doesn't mean destroy, it just does what it says, it makes memory space free.  So after using free() the programmer is still free to use the pointer by reallocating memory space on to the heap with realloc().

Example:

```
int * ptr = (int*) calloc(1, sizeof(int));
*ptr = 100;
printf("ptr contains = %d\n", *ptr);
free(ptr);
ptr = (int*) realloc(ptr, (2 * sizeof(int)));
*ptr = 100;
*(ptr + 1) = 200;
printf("ptr = %d ptr+1 = %d\n", *ptr, *(ptr + 1));
```

you will set it to NULL only when you are really done with that pointer and you don't want it to be free but rather destroyed, inaccessible.